# Guardar los valores de JTextField en variables tipo double

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente codigo, y mi problema es que no se como hacer el action listener de mi boton "Aceptar" para que guarde lo escrito en los JTextFields en las variables tipo double

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Aprendizaje  extends JFrame {
private JLabel lx1,lx2,ly1;
private JTextField  textx1,textx2,texty1,
                    textx1a,textx2a,texty1a,
                    textx1b,textx2b,texty1b,
                    textx1c,textx2c,texty1c;

public double x1, x2, x1a, x1b, x2a, x2b, x1c, x2c, y, y1, y2, y3,
w1, w2, umbral;

private JButton button1;
public Aprendizaje(){
this.setLayout(null);
this.setSize(350,350);            
this.setTitle("thisrendizaje");
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//Instanciando Cuadros de Texto         
lx1 = new JLabel("X1");
this.add(lx1);
lx1.setBounds(25, 15, 25, 20);
textx1 = new JTextField();
this.add(textx1);
textx1.setBounds(25, 35, 35, 30);
lx2 = new JLabel("X2");
this.add(lx2);
lx2.setBounds(125, 15, 25, 20);
textx2 = new JTextField();
this.add(textx2);
textx2.setBounds(125, 35, 35, 30);
ly1 = new JLabel("Y1");
this.add(ly1);
ly1.setBounds(250, 10, 25, 30);
texty1 = new JTextField();
this.add(texty1);
texty1.setBounds(250, 35, 35, 30);
textx1a = new JTextField();
this.add(textx1a);
textx1a.setBounds(25, 90, 35, 30);
textx2a = new JTextField();
this.add(textx2a);
textx2a.setBounds(125, 90, 35, 30);
texty1a = new JTextField();
this.add(texty1a);
texty1a.setBounds(250, 90, 35, 30);
textx1b = new JTextField();
this.add(textx1b);
textx1b.setBounds(25, 145, 35, 30);
textx2b = new JTextField();
this.add(textx2b);
textx2b.setBounds(125, 145, 35, 30);
texty1b = new JTextField();
this.add(texty1b);
texty1b.setBounds(250, 145, 35, 30);
textx1c = new JTextField();
this.add(textx1c);
textx1c.setBounds(25, 195, 35, 30);
textx2c = new JTextField();
this.add(textx2c);
textx2c.setBounds(125, 195, 35, 30);
texty1c = new JTextField();
this.add(texty1c);
texty1c.setBounds(250, 195, 35, 30);
//Fin cuadros de texto
//Botones
button1 = new JButton("Aceptar");
this.add(button1);
button1.setBounds(75, 300, 100, 20);
  }
}
```

Por ejemplo el valor del el TextField textx1 se guardaria en el double x1, el valor de textx2 en el double x2 y asi.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un pequeño ejemplo de como usar el listener (aunque en este caso mando cadenas de texto a una tabla)

```
tablaBuscar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getClickCount() == 2){
                 int filaseleccionada = tablaBuscar.getSelectedRow();
                 if (filaseleccionada== -1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha seleccionado ninguna fila");
                }
                else{
                    try{   
                        //llenando los Campos-columnas
                        txtId.setText(tablaBuscar.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 0).toString());
                        txtDescripcion.setText(tablaBuscar.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 1).toString());
                        txtcargo.setText(tablaBuscar.getValueAt(filaseleccionada, 2).toString());


                    }
                    catch(Exception ex2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al mostrar datos del registro;\n"+ex2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
});
```

Puedes cambiar en la primera linea de codigo el `tablaBuscar.addMouseListener...` por tu boton: `botonAceptar.addMouseListener`... Luego solo te faltaria asignar a cada variable los valores de los jTextFields

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir el valor de un `JTextField` a `double` usa el método `parseDouble()` de la clase `Double`. Te pongo cómo sería:

```
button1 = new JButton("Aceptar");
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x1 = Double.parseDouble(textx1.getText());
        x2 = Double.parseDouble(textx2.getText());
        ...
    }
);
this.add(button1);
```

Te lo he escrito con el propio método para añadir el listener ya que veo que también tenías alguna duda con eso (corrígeme si me equivoco). El método `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` se utiliza normalmente para controlar el la acción de hacer click del usuario. Si utilizas `mousePressed` como ya te han propuesto, solamente estarías controlando la acción de hacer click con el ratón por lo que tu aplicación no funcionaría correctamente en pantallas táctiles por ejemplo ni en ningún dispositivo que no tenga un ratón.

P.D.: Recuerda añadir las validaciones del `JTextField` necesarias para que el usuario sólo pueda introducir valores `double`. Si no lo haces y el usuario introduce, por ejemplo, un `String` o cualquier otra cosa, tu aplicación lanzará excepción y crasheará.

Espero que te sirva :)